# Tensorflow model always predict the same wrong value

Tags: node.js, tensorflow, machine-learning, tensorflow.js

I am actually learn to build a machine learning in nodejs: i choose [tensorflow](https://js.tensorflow.org/api/latest/) API for this.
The goal of this machine learning, it's to give a input of 14 entries and to return a number in relation of thus 14 entries. (I cannot describe more the context because I am in traineeship, and i don't know if i allowed to talk about this.) 
But the model always predict wrong values, and i dont't know why. I tried different loss/optimizer function, differents layers model configuration, different layer activation... but the model always give me a float value.

I tried to replace the input/output value to 0.3, the prediction return me a value between 0.1 and 0.3. (tested 3 times). But the loss value downcrease during the training, that seem to work better.

I also tried to increase the training epochs to 1000, no results :/

First of all, I create a function to build the model network. My model have a input layer of 14 units, then 2 hidden layers of 5 units and then the output layer with only one unit. (All the layer are in 'sigmoid' activation, and are dense type.)

```
const get_model = async () => {
    const model = tf.sequential();

    const input_layer = tf.layers.dense({
        units: 13,
        inputShape: [14],
        activation: 'sigmoid',
    });
    model.add(input_layer)

    let left = 3;
    while(left >= 2){

        const step_layer = tf.layers.dense({
            units: 5,
            activation: 'sigmoid',
        });
        model.add(step_layer)

        left --;
    }

    const output = tf.layers.dense({
        units: 1,
        activation: 'sigmoid',
    });

    model.add(output)

    model.compile({
        optimizer: tf.train.sgd(0.01),
        loss: tf.losses.absoluteDifference,
        metrics: 'accuracy',
    })

    return model;
}
```

To test the model, during the train, I always give a list of 13 number (all the values are 100), and i always give the following value: 100.

```
const get_output = () => {
    return 100;
}
const get_input = () => {
    return [
        100,
        100,
        100,
        100,
        100,
        100,
        100,
        100,
        100,
        100,
        100,
        100,
        100,
        100,
    ];
}
```

I have two functions to transform value to tensor value.

```
const get_input_tensor = (value) => {
    return tf.tensor([value],[1,14])
}
const get_output_tensor = (value) => {
    return tf.tensor(
        [Math.floor(value)],
        [1,1]
    )
}
```

Then i get the model, i train the model and try the prediction.

```
(async () => {
    const model = await get_model();

    let left = 20;
    while(left >= 0){
        const input = get_input();
        const output = get_output();

        await model.fit(get_input_tensor(input),get_output_tensor(output),{
            batchSize: 30,
            epochs: 10,
            shuffle: true,
        });

        left--;
    }

    const input = get_input();

    const output = model.predict(get_input_tensor(input));

    output.print();
})();
```

During the training, the loss value is close to 100. This highlight that the model always return me close a value close to 1.

This is my console during the training:

```
Epoch 8 / 10
eta=0.0 ====================================================================> 
11ms 10943us/step - loss=99.14 
Epoch 9 / 10
eta=0.0 ====================================================================> 
10ms 10351us/step - loss=99.14 
Epoch 10 / 10
eta=0.0 ====================================================================> 
12ms 12482us/step - loss=99.14
```

Then when i try the prediction, the model return me a value close to 1.

This is the print tensor of the prediction.

```
Tensor
     [[0.8586583],]
```

May you help me ? I don't know what goes wrong. Is it possible to have a prediction more than 1 ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I finally solve the problems !

My layers use the following activation: 'sigmoid'. sigmoid is a function where the values are include between 0 and 1, that the reason why I getting the same values.
(The activation 'relu' is not really what i expect)

I set the activation to 'linear', but this activation make the loss value to NaN during the training, then I switched the optimizers to adam, and this resolves the problem :)

Answer (score 3):

Here is a simple model that will predict 100 from an input of 14 values. It is often common to sample the input values to be between 0 and 1. It improves the convergence of steepest descent algorithms.

As for the reason why the model is predicting wrong values; there are general answers [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55943498/model-is-not-learning/55954415#55954415)

```js
(async () => {
  const model = tf.sequential({
    layers: [tf.layers.dense({units: 1, inputShape: [14], activation: 'relu', kernelInitializer: 'ones'})]
  });
  model.compile({optimizer: 'sgd', loss: 'meanSquaredError'});
  await model.fit(tf.ones([1, 14]), tf.tensor([100], [1, 1]), {epochs: 100})
  model.predict(tf.ones([1, 14])).print();
 })()
```

```html
<html>
  <head>
    <!-- Load TensorFlow.js -->
    <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/@tensorflow/tfjs@latest"> </script>
  </head>

  <body>
  </body>
</html>
```