# TensorflowJS in a 2-dimension simple problem

Tags: javascript, tensorflow, tensorflow.js

I am playing with TensorflowJS and I am surprised by the (bad) results I got.
Here is the problem I am working on:
you have a 2D square from the top left (0,0) to the bottom right (1,1). Each corner has a color in RGB as follow:

top-left: black

top-right: red

bottom-right: green

bottom-left: blue

I want to infer the color on a point which is in the square.

I have set a simple Tensorflow model. After a simple trainng, I test it on the bottom right... and instead of getting something close to the green, I got bad results.
Could you please tell me where I am doing something wrong? 
Thanks

```
async function test() 
{
  tf.setBackend('cpu');

  const model = tf.sequential();
  model.add(tf.layers.dense({units: 3, inputShape: [2] }));

  model.compile({loss: 'meanSquaredError', optimizer: 'sgd'});

  const xs = tf.tensor([0,0, 1,0, 1,1, 0,1 ], [4, 2]);
  const ys = tf.tensor([ 

                         [ 0, 0, 0 ], // black
                         [ 1, 0, 0 ], // red
                         [ 0, 1, 0 ], // green
                         [ 0, 0, 1 ], // blue

                       ], [4, 3]);

  await model.fit(xs, ys, {epochs: 5000});

  const input = tf.tensor([1,1], [1, 2]);
  console.log(model.predict(input).dataSync());
}
```

My results:

```
Float32Array(3) [0.25062745809555054, 0.7481716275215149, 0.2501324415206909]
```

Comment: There are a few problems with your learning algorithm and data. But I think the biggest one is that your layer has a default ('linear') activation. Since output values are like probabilities for multiple classes, you want to use `actions: 'softmax'`. Also, typical machine learning data is more diverse and variable (noisier) than the data you're using in this example.

Comment: Sorry, I meant `activation: 'softmax'` for your `tf.layers.dense()` call.

Comment: I tried to set the activation to softmax... but this did not solve the problem. I made a representation of the square in color. see next link. ![image](http://www.seb-d.com/tensorflowjs/image.png).

Answer (score 0):

The model is using a linear activation, which can output correct results only if the features and the labels are linearily dependant ( **y = ax+b**). A different activation needs to be used.

Often a model needs to be fine tuned, meaning that a different set of parameters needs to be used until one finds a model with best accuracy - it is called fined tuning. Below is a model with a set of parameters that has a low accuracy. One needs to keep in mind that this is not "**the**" set of parameters. It is "**a**" set of parameters. See this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55943498/model-is-not-learning/55954415#55954415) about how to fine tuned a model.

```js
(async() => {
 const model = tf.sequential();
 model.add(tf.layers.dense({units: 18, inputShape: [2]}));
 model.add(tf.layers.dense({units: 14, activation: 'relu6'}));
 model.add(tf.layers.dense({units: 3, activation: 'relu6'}));

const xs = tf.tensor([0,0, 1,0, 1,1, 0,1 ], [4, 2]);
  const ys = tf.tensor([ 

                         [ 0, 0, 0 ], // black
                         [ 1, 0, 0 ], // red
                         [ 0, 1, 0 ], // green
                         [ 0, 0, 1 ], // blue

                       ], [4, 3]);
const optimizer = tf.train.sgd(0.000001)
model.compile({loss: 'meanSquaredError', optimizer: 'adam'});
  await model.fit(xs, ys, {
    epochs: 500,
    callbacks: {onEpochEnd: (epoch, logs) => console.log(logs.loss)}
  });

const input = tf.tensor([1,1], [1, 2]);
  console.log(model.predict(input).dataSync());
 })()
```

```html
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/@tensorflow/tfjs/dist/tf.min.js"> </script>
```

Even if the above model has a low accuracy, resulting in better prediction, the problem solved here seems not to be a regression problem. If the goal is just to pick a color out of three, we rather have a classification problem. The difference would be to have a `softmax activation` layer on the last layer and the loss function would be a `binaryCrossentropy` (respectively `categoricalCrossentropy`) for 2 (respectively more than 2) units on the last layer.

```js
(async() => {
 const model = tf.sequential();
 model.add(tf.layers.dense({units: 18, inputShape: [2]}));
 model.add(tf.layers.dense({units: 14, activation: 'relu6'}));
 model.add(tf.layers.dense({units: 4, activation: 'softmax'}));

const xs = tf.tensor([0,0, 1,0, 1,1, 0,1 ], [4, 2]);
const ys = tf.oneHot([0, 1, 2, 3], 4)
// 0 for black 
// 1 for red 
// 2 for green 
// 3 for blue
ys.print()

model.compile({loss: 'categoricalCrossentropy', optimizer: 'sgd'});
  await model.fit(xs, ys, {
    epochs: 100,
    callbacks: {onEpochEnd: (epoch, logs) => console.log(logs.loss)}
  });

const input = tf.tensor([1,1], [1, 2]);
const output = model.predict(input)
output.print()
output.argMax(1).print(); // result will be 2 for green
 })()
```

```html
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/@tensorflow/tfjs/dist/tf.min.js"> </script>
```

Comment: Thanks edkeveked! The loss value is good... but when I try the following, I still have bad results... this is so strange!!!  `  var input = tf.tensor([0,0], [1, 2]);
  console.log("top-left", model.predict(input).dataSync());
 
  input = tf.tensor([0,1], [1, 2]);
  console.log("top-right", model.predict(input).dataSync());

  input = tf.tensor([1,1], [1, 2]);
  console.log("bottom-right", model.predict(input).dataSync());

  input = tf.tensor([1,0], [1, 2]);
  console.log("bottom-left", model.predict(input).dataSync());
`

Comment: Each time, you run the code, the weights values are randomly initialized. Depending of these values, the model prediction might be erroneous. But running the code multiple times, you will see that it will predict correct value for `[0,0]`. You can try to save the weights values for which the model accuracy is what you are looking for

Comment: I confirm that... it is too random-dependant... sometimes the top-left is good and sometimes false. But I see no way to have a global good solution, unfortunatly.

Comment: Save the model each time you train, they are called checkpoints. It is a common thing to do when training DL model. The second model is more stable than the first. Because as explained in the answer, it is the way to go for the kind of problem you are solving