# tensorflow.js model does not learn

Tags: machine-learning, neural-network, tensorflow.js

My model doesn´t learn.. It is supposed to do a softmax calculation in the end. I want as a result a classification (quit or no-quit). The model should predict if the customer will quit. I am giving the quit-column as label and have 196 input-features.

My visor says there is no learning at all. But then I am not certain, how the visor will get information, if my model learns. I am very new to javascript and would appreciate any help.

```
ngOnInit() {
  this.train();
}


async train(): Promise<any> {
  const csvUrl = '/assets/little.csv';
  const csvDataset = tf.data.csv(
    csvUrl,
    {
      columnConfigs: {
        quit: {
          isLabel: true
        }
      },
      delimiter:','
    });
  const numOfFeatures = (await csvDataset.columnNames()).length -1;      
  console.log(numOfFeatures);
  const flattenedDataset =
  csvDataset
  .map(({xs, ys}: any) =>
    {
      // Convert xs(features) and ys(labels) from object form (keyed by
      // column name) to array form.
      return {xs:Object.values(xs), ys:Object.values(ys)};
    }).batch(10);    
  console.log(flattenedDataset.toArray());      

  const model = tf.sequential({
    layers: [
      tf.layers.dense({inputShape: [196], units: 100, activation: 'relu'}),
      tf.layers.dense({units: 100, activation: 'relu'}),
      tf.layers.dense({units: 100, activation: 'relu'}),        
      tf.layers.dense({units: 1, activation: 'softmax'}),        
    ]
  }); 
  await trainModel(model, flattenedDataset);
  const surface = { name: 'Model Summary', tab: 'Model Inspection'};
  tfvis.show.modelSummary(surface, model);    
  console.log('Done Training');
}

async function trainModel(model, flattenedDataset) {
  // Prepare the model for training.  
  model.compile({
    optimizer: tf.train.adam(),
    loss: tf.losses.sigmoidCrossEntropy,
    metrics: ['accuracy']
  });

  const batchSize = 32;
  const epochs = 50;

  return await model.fitDataset(flattenedDataset, {
    batchSize,
    epochs,
    shuffle: true,
    callbacks: tfvis.show.fitCallbacks(
      { name: 'Training Performance' },
      ['loss'],
      { height: 200, callbacks: ['onEpochEnd'] }
    )
  });
}
```

Comment: Did you try a different loss function such as `categoricalCrossentropy` ? And change the config to be this way: `loss: 'categoricalCrossentropy'`

Comment: With your change, the loss-Value stays at a much lower level, but is still a flat line. Before, the line was at around 0.75. With your change it stays at around 0.00005. But still the algorithm doesnt seem to learn..

Comment: The softmax activation is for classification problem. Your model seems not to do a classification. Your last layer has a single unit which indicates that you are doing a regression. Your model is most likely not learning because of that

Comment: That would be a good explanation! I updated the question. Can you provide a suggestion, how I must change the code, so the model does classification correctly? I want the output to be a classification of quit/no-quit.

Comment: The number of units for the last layer is the number of categories. There are two categories in `quit` and `no-quit`. Additionnaly your labels should be one-hot encoded. More general answers on why a model is not learning can be found [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55943498/model-is-not-learning/55954415#55954415)

Comment: That was the solution! I added a column non-quit which I defined to be 1-quit. Then I changed the code to         columnConfigs: {
          quit: {
            isLabel: true
          },noquit:{
            isLabel: true
          }
        }, and the last layer to         tf.layers.dense({units: 2, activation: 'softmax'}),        Now it is learning !!! Thank you very much! What a pity you didn´t put it as answer so I cannot accept and upvote it. Thanks again.

Comment: I just added it as an answer. Feel free to accept and upvote it :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The number of units for the last layer is the number of categories. There are two categories `quit` and `no-quit`. Additionnaly your labels should be one-hot encoded. More general answers on why a model is not learning can be found [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55943498/model-is-not-learning/55954415#55954415).

Comment: That was the solution! I added a column non-quit which I defined to be 1 - quit (So I am  one hot-encoded there). Then I changed the code to columnConfigs: { quit: { isLabel: true },noquit:{ isLabel: true } }, and the last layer to tf.layers.dense({units: 2, activation: 'softmax'}), Now it is learning !!! Thank you very much!