# TFJS model only predicting the same value for binary classification task

Tags: javascript, tensorflow, machine-learning, classification, tensorflow.js

I have a dataset (which contains both the data and the label) with the size of [299,13], and the model keeps outputting / predicting the same value. This is a binary classification task. How would I make my model predict values which are not constantly the same?

Here is the code (with some dummy data):

```
//X is the data and y is the label

    
   var Dataset = tf.tensor([[1,0.491821360184978,9,314,0.504585169147173,542,1231,3213,1,0.267304071302649,3,0.615917680092409,0],
        [0,0.72959029133292,3,758,0.402582737085955,400,1788,4599,0,0.532702887951197,4,0.18630897965037,1],
        [1,0.198764110760428,5,787,0.65507860022684,887,192,4831,1,0.739456077544426,3,0.100068056951143,1],
        [0,0.583574833590476,5,596,0.933996451580092,631,331,811,0,0.258445986493932,7,0.811276729811182,0],
        [1,0.701499878184206,8,854,0.0326334179806069,845,470,4930,1,0.825469683527519,1,0.448086959665654,1],
        [0,0.954482878414911,2,468,0.736300149681564,557,3110,739,0,0.325783042694677,5,0.43488580142501,1],
        [1,0.384845877769,2,662,0.265402742189238,649,384,1158,1,0.484884260891815,2,0.915444292219105,0],
        [1,0.379266474923531,9,551,0.275982850450116,1022,3329,1413,1,0.237295089390298,4,0.817104709627837,1],
        [1,0.691365367558705,8,549,0.479627221800976,796,3381,495,1,0.37129382411555,9,0.332832739155564,1],
        [0,0.433042848178662,5,529,0.545178403950882,842,4768,506,0,0.386370525896832,9,0.189942077251933,0],
        [1,0.611272282663452,4,823,0.737901576655264,839,2724,1787,1,0.365032317656007,6,0.884073622694046,0],
        [0,0.0084315409129881,5,352,0.76858549557176,476,685,4796,0,0.302944943656102,1,0.849655932794213,1],
        [0,0.977380232874908,6,701,0.588833228576897,999,2897,3325,0,0.418024491281536,2,0.631872118440871,1],
        [1,0.419601058571829,10,384,0.0157052616592944,1009,4438,113,1,0.909015627566542,1,0.0297684897733232,0],
        [0,0.739471449044276,4,836,0.0430176780439737,1030,1456,3932,0,0.331426481315121,6,0.734008754824423,0],
        [1,0.00209807072438295,4,352,0.499622407429238,418,1912,4452,1,0.727130871883893,8,0.157427964683612,0],
        [1,0.956533819923862,10,681,0.196708599930969,829,4562,1718,1,0.233193195569506,7,0.60582783922237,0],
        [1,0.504637155233183,8,809,0.608861975627751,717,130,4194,1,0.134197560919101,6,0.375188428842507,0],
        [0,0.747363884375055,1,522,0.868234577182028,849,3529,1192,0,0.0322641640468155,5,0.185973206518818,0],
        [0,0.244142898027225,10,402,0.0280582030746698,315,3576,3882,0,0.724916254371562,8,0.062229775169706,1],
        [0,0.858414851618448,8,459,0.367325906336267,616,930,3892,0,0.177388425930446,10,0.859824526007041,1],
        [1,0.921555604905976,2,863,0.821166873626313,528,1624,1289,1,0.366243396916411,5,0.453840754701258,1],
        [1,0.171321120311715,1,524,0.177251413832862,468,1608,3123,1,0.192861821442111,8,0.122983286410146,0],
        [0,0.539946042901786,6,692,0.817780349862711,392,1053,4891,0,0.409578972921785,3,0.0453862502541893,1],
        [1,0.996848843212564,5,549,0.877740438211017,762,3046,843,1,0.888578696082088,8,0.877971306478434,1],
        [0,0.218116987741582,3,655,0.240496962520226,407,1001,1474,0,0.976212355833712,2,0.936396547703282,1]])
    function onBatchEnd(batch, logs) {
        console.log('Accuracy', logs.acc);
    }
    
    var x = Dataset.slice([0, 0], [-1, 12])
    const y = Dataset.slice([0, 12], [-1, 1])
    
    const model = tf.sequential({
        layers: [
            tf.layers.dense({ inputShape: [12], units: 12, activation: "sigmoid" }),
            tf.layers.dense({ units: 8, activation: "relu" }),
            tf.layers.dense({ units: 4, activation: "tanh" }),
            tf.layers.dense({ units: 1, activation: "sigmoid" })
        ]
    })
    
    model.compile({
        optimizer: tf.train.adam(0.001),
        loss: "binaryCrossentropy",
        metrics: ["accuracy"]
    })
    
    model.fit(x, y, {
        shuffle: true,
        epochs: 100,
        //validationSplit: 0.1,
        callbacks: { onBatchEnd }
    }).then(info => {
        var predictions = model.predict(x)
        console.log('Final accuracy', info.history.acc);
        console.log("Predictions: ")
        console.log(predictions.dataSync());
    })
```

Comment: 299 data samples might not be enough

Comment: Thanks, I just want my model to be able to predict a value which is not constantly the same. Do you have any idea how to do that?

Comment: Use a larger dataset with more labels. Also, your problem might be related to programming issues

Comment: That programming issue is what I am trying to solve with this question

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Model is not learning](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55943498/model-is-not-learning)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The model is doing a binary classification using the `sigmoid` activation. Therefore, the last unit should be `2`.

```
tf.layers.dense({ units: 2, activation: "sigmoid" })
```

The labels tensor `y` has the innermost right dimension size 1 with values being either 0 or 1. This tensor should be onehot encoded.

```
const x = Dataset.slice([0, 0], [-1, 12])
const y = Dataset.slice([0, 12], [-1, 1])

z = y.cast('int32').reshape([-1]).oneHot(2)
z.print()
console.log(z.shape) // [26, 2]
// now use z instead of y
```

Answer (score 0):

```
   tf.layers.dense({ units: 1, activation: "sigmoid" })
```

You have only one class prediction, but for binary classification you need two target classes and softmax activation. See cs321n notes for [Linear Classification](https://cs231n.github.io/linear-classify/).